# What does Data Transfer Out in Amazon S3 refer to?

Tags: amazon-s3

I am having trouble understanding the `Data Transfer Out pricing` part of [Amazon S3 costs](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/#pricing)

Their [FAQ talk about](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#How_much_does_Amazon_S3_cost) how to calculate it but I am not able to understand the difference between **Data transfer out** and *Requests** pricing..

Isn't `Data transfer out` the same as `requests`? The page also talks about `Data transfer In` being free for EU and then proceeds to explain the costs for `Put requests`

---

Sorry for this off topic question, I checked the FAQ on SuperUser, Programmers, ServerFault and WebMasters - none of them looked like a good place for this question (and If I'm going to ask an out-of-topic question, I thought I'd at least pick a place where I am comfortable being wrong)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Data transfer out` is the number of bytes transmitted, whereas the `requests` refer to the number of distinct requests. You normally make one request per download, but you can transfer several megabytes afterwards.

Comment: I see, so I pay twice if I want to get, say, an image? once for the request itself, and once for the size of the picture.. okay, that makes a sense now.. thanks!